# Having issues getting data from api call

Tags: javascript, api

Hey guys Im making a api call and getting a response I have not yet encountered . my api call is basic and looks like

```
async function getStudents(){
          const response = await fetch('url');
          const studentData = response.json();
    
         console.log(studentData)
```

> Promise { : "pending" } : "fulfilled" : Object {
> students: (25) […] }

and these are the results I get, Normally I could do something like `studentData.students` to get that object but nothing seems to get the correct object. what am I doing wroing?

Comment: Looks like a typo.  You forgot to `await` the call to `response.json()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: `response.json()` returns a promise so you should use `await` again: `const studentData = await response.json();`

Comment: ha! thanks that worked. appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like this :

```
async function getStudents(){
   fetch('url')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
  .catch(error=>console.log(error,"error  occured"));

}
```

Comment: Why would OP use promises instead of async-await? Especially in an async function.